# How to edit a page in the SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint

I have some custom codes in form of HTML which I wanted to add to the SharePoint. I find out there are two ways to do it, one is using the SharePoint Designer and the other one is uploading the page. However, this is local SharePoint in my Windows Server and I want to modify the page locally because I have limitation when using the Designer and Upload  page. I also don't want to add a new page and I would like to modify the current page using my own code.
Are you able to help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the page> insert the **Embed Code** web part to add custom HTML codes:

[image]

More information for your reference:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-add-html-page-to-sharepoint-site